# App crashes on drawing of UILabel - NSString is a zombie

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm working on an iPad app that has a slider that is used to scroll through data. When scrolling, a map is displayed and the data is updated. The problem is, if you scroll fast enough (or somehow trigger the race condition), the app crashes on accessing a zombie NSString. I've been able to track it down in the Profiler and found this:

```
Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp       Size    Responsible Library     Responsible Caller
Malloc      1       01:55.166.466   16      Foundation              -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]
Autorelease <null>  01:55.166.472   0       Foundation              +[NSString stringWithFormat:]
CFRetain    2       01:55.166.473   0       My Program              -[StateView updateVotes:]
CFRetain    3       01:55.166.476   0       UIKit                   -[UILabel setText:]
CFRelease   2       01:55.166.504   0       My Program              -[StateView updateVotes:]
CFRelease   1       01:55.177.661   0       Foundation              -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
CFRelease   0       01:55.439.090   0       UIKit                   -[UILabel setText:]
Zombie      -1      01:55.439.109   0       UIKit                   -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:lineBreakMode:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:]
```

I'm using ARC on iOS5, so I'm not in control of the retain/release at all. Even if I was, looking at the above, it is correct. The problem seems to be a race condition between the drawing function and the UILabel string actually changing. The UILabel releases the first string, as a new one has been set, but the drawing function is holding a reference to it somehow, but did not retain it.

As a note, I have not modified the UILabel in any way.

Any ideas?

--- Code added as update:

Slider update:

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    float position = slider.value - 1790.0f;
    int year;
    if(position <= 0.0f) {
        year = 1789;
    } else {
        year = 1792 + (floor(position / 4.0f)*4);
    }
    [self setYear:year];
}
```

setYear:

```
-(void)setYear:(int)year {
if (year == currentYear) {
        // year didn't change, so don't do anything
        return;
    }

    [yearLabel setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", year]];
    currentYear = year;

    [self getMapForYear:year];
}
```

getMapForYear:

```
-(void) getMapForYear:(int)year {
    [self setToMap:[historicalData objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:year]];
}
```

setToMap:

```
-(void) setToMap:(HistoricalMap *)map {
    // Label the map
    for (State *state in [map states]) {
        [mapController setVotes:[state votes] forState:[state abbreviation]];
    }
}
```

setVotes:forState:

```
-(void)setVotes:(NSNumber *)votes forState:(NSString *)stateAbbreviation {

    StateView *state = [states objectForKey:stateAbbreviation];
    if (state == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid State Votes -- %@", stateAbbreviation);
        return;
    }
    [state updateVotes:votes];
    [state setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

updateVotes:

```
-(void)updateVotes:(NSNumber *)newVotes {
    [self setVotes:newVotes];

    NSString *voteString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", newVotes];

    [voteLabel setText:voteString];
    if ([newVotes isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
        [[self voteLabel] setHidden:YES];
        [[self stateAbbreviationLabel] setHidden:YES];
    } else {
        [[self stateAbbreviationLabel] setHidden:NO];
        [[self voteLabel] setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code where you are updating the data as the slider's value changes. Remember this can be called hundreds of times a second if the slider is continuous.

Comment: Is any of this threaded in any way?  What you show above shouldn't behave the way that you describe, with the string being released before it is drawn, unless there's a different thread pulling the rug out from underneath you somewhere.  I don't know that you can have a race condition like this with only one thread involved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are attempting to do far too much during the slider's movement. Creating and executing core data fetch requests alone would seem to be overkill, let alone updating the entire GUI and a screenful of labels. Have you tested the performance of this on a device?

It could be worth profiling these sections of code and seeing where the time is spent. You could look at caching the fetch requests or the results, for example, or you may have to resort to updating only when the slider has stopped, or only for every `n` increments along the path.

Comment: It was running fine as far as performance was concerned. I've moved the core data call out of the slider update and stored it in the controller. Updates are faster, but I encountered the same issue.

Comment: I think I've resolved the problem by creating and storing the string in the core data managed object. That way the string exists as long as the core data object does. Thanks for the help though. Appreciate the thoughts on improving performance.

Comment: Ok, glad you've got it working - it does sound like a cool effect, scrubbing through history!

Answer (score 0):

You havw several memory-leaks with NSString:

```
[yearLabel setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", year]]; // leak
```

Create string with `stringWithFormat` method instead

```
[yearLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", year]];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had changed it trying to track down the zombie and hadn't switched it back.

Comment: @bertuccio255 - Actually, if you're using ARC here, there should be no difference between the two.  You shouldn't be leaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
   [NSString stringWithFormat:   **is the best way formatting the string than any other..**
```

Comment: As I pointed out for beryllium's answer, under ARC there is no effective difference between `+stringWithFormat:` and `-initWithFormat:`.  Also, claiming that `+stringWithFormat:` is the best in all cases is a pretty broad statement.